# Fitting data in Gnuplot using other data for fitting function definition

Tags: gnuplot, data-fitting

I would like to use some model function `f(x)` to fit my experimental data `data.dat`, which contain unwanted background (not included in model). I have (normalized) background data in the xy-type datafile `bgr.dat`  Unfortunately, I can't subtract background directly, because I don't know exact magnitude of the background; my data contains background multiplied by constant `const`. Any idea how to redefine model function to include background and fit it like this?

```
fit f(x) `data.dat` via par1, par2,...,parN, const
```

`par1, par2,...,parN` are other parametres of the model

Comment: If you don't know the const-multiplier with which the (additive?) background noise is contained in your recorded data, you're in a world of trouble. If you have a model function, say a*x**2 + b*x + c and a white-noise-type background of unknown magnitude (multiplier) d, how would you distinguish between the absolute term contributions by c and d?

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is Linux, you can use `paste` command to combine data.dat and bgr.dat into a new data file (new_data.dat). The new_data.dat should have four columns, then in gnuplot:

```
fit f(x) `new_data.dat` using 1:($2-const*$4) via par1,par2,...,parN, const
```

which subtracts the background multiplied by const on the fly.